# table view cells with background image not filling the whole width of screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi i am new for ios and in my app i have created one `UITableView` and i have set background image for `UITableViewcell` but image not filling the whole width of screen as like below screen. Why this problem is occuring?

I mean `UITableViewCell` left and right sides gap is coming images is not filling whole cell width.

please help me someone

### my code:-

```
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController ()
{
    UITableView * tableList;
    TableCell * Cell;
}

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tableList = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    tableList.delegate = self;
    tableList.dataSource = self;
    tableList.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    [self.view addSubview:tableList];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    Cell = (TableCell *)[tableList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (Cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        Cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    //UIImageView *imageBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        Cell.backGroundImage.image =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_top.png"];
    } else if (indexPath.row == 9) {
       Cell.backGroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_bottom.png"];
    } else {
       Cell.backGroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_middle.png"];
    }

    //imageBackground.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    //Cell.backgroundView = imageBackground;

    return Cell;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return 44.0;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
    }
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}

@end
```

[image]

Comment: Did you print the imgview frame and the table cell frame ?

Comment: Does your class inherit from `UITableViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my wrong post before. The issue you might be facing may be because of autolayouts. Check if the image view has proper autolayouts assigned or not.